# Use google maps idle event with the sebastianm angular 2 google maps

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, angular2-google-maps

[image]After seeing that i can load the google maps API in my Compnent Class for the **sebastianm angular 2 google maps** like:

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
            types: ["(regions)"],
            componentRestrictions: {country: "za"}

        });
```

I would like to use the google maps events, For example in my Component Class, i have a member function that's triggered by a click event, in this function i wanted to listen to the **idle** event like:

```
getMessage(): void {
         this.myService.getMessage().then((res) => {     
         this.map = res;
         this.lat = this.map.maps[0].geometry.location.lat;
         this.lng = this.map.maps[0].geometry.location.lng;
         console.log(this.lat,this.lng);  
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
           //HERE I WANT TO SCROLL to THE MAP ELEMENT IN THE DOM
        });
        })

}
```

I am new to using the google maps API and i am struggling to get the **map object** that is required by functions like **addListener/addDomListener**, how do i get the required **map object** which is the first parameter for the **addListener/addDomListener** as stated in the google maps API.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the `this.map` variable you create on line 2 of the getMessage method, or `this.map.maps[0]`?

Comment: I am not sure, but that is a response from the NodeJS server i am using the Google maps client in the server

Comment: Or perhaps it is the thing is i am not sure if that object is of the Maps type

Comment: what does `console.log(this.map)` give you?

Comment: @duncan, i am AFK now can i reply again later? i will attach a screenshot of the response from the developer tools or just the JSON object i am getting from the server as a comment here

Comment: Yes perfect, in your own time!

Comment: @duncan forgive me for the wait, i have edited my question, i've added the picture that show the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134117/discussion-between-teebo-and-duncan).